# Can you use a SWF as a dependency for a Flex Mojos Maven build

Tags: apache-flex, maven-2, flash, flex-mojos

I have a maven project with flex-mojos 3.1.0. Can I have a module with swf packaging and configure a dependency on it in another module? When I do, I get a compilation error.

```
project    
| - module1:swf  
| - module2:swf
```

module2/pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>swf</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue, however my problem doesn't manifest itself as a dependency identification error, rather it manifests itself as a compilation error of an underlying object in module2. I get: "Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: <module 1 class name>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be impossible

Comment: Fast forward 2014, this is possible unless I mis understand something basic about the question. But I have been doing this for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

If you need module-to-module dependency to ensure correct build order for your modules then you can simply create a parent pom for both modules and arange build order in it.